# open folder from Network with Powershell

Tags: powershell, net-use

I would like to open a txt.File from a sharedFolder with Powershell. The problem is, that it has to run whether an user is logged on or not. I'm looking for something like net-use. 
The Program should also check, whether the psDrive exists or not.
Is it possible if I do that like this?

```
new-psdrive -name Z -psprovider FileSystem -root \\vcs.view
```

---

It works like that: 
I map and then I check whether the file exists:

```
#mapping
try
{
    new-psdrive -name Z -psprovider FileSystem -root $ShareFolder
}
catch
{
    echo "WriteMessageTOAdmin ERROR!!"
    exit
}

$folderPath = "Z:\users.txt"

if(!(test-Path -path $folderPath))
{
    echo "WriteMessageTOAdmin ERROR!!"
    exit
}
```

Comment: new-psdrive -name Z -psprovider FileSystem -root \\server\sharename is like net use z: \\server\sharename.

Comment: are you getting specific errors from this approach?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to map a network share to open a file on a network share:

> Get-Content \\server\sharename\foo.txt

Works just fine as does using `Test-Path` on a UNC path e.g.

> Test-Path \\server\sharename\foo.txt

Is there a reason you need to map the share to a local drive?

Comment: The programm should write an e-mail after the process but that does not work. It watches a file and when the file change the program should load the content and write a mail afterwards.

Comment: Just don't forget surrounding the path between double quotes.

Comment: You do *not* need to quote paths in PowerShell unless the path contains spaces.