# Count files in a network folder using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, monitoring

I've searched numerous MSDN/Technet and StackOverflow articles regarding this but I can't find a solution to my problem.
SO references below.

I am trying to run a script on my server that simply counts the files in a folder on a network location.

I can get it working if it's a local folder, and I can get it working when I map the network drive. However I can't use a network drive because I'll be running this script from a web interface that doesn't have a user account (local drives work fine).

My script is:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem \\storage\folder -File  
$Files.count
```

I get the error:

```
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path '\\storage\folder' because it does not exist.
```

[0][open folder from Network with Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875769/open-folder-from-network-with-powershell)
[1][File counting with Powershell commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239905/file-counting-with-powershell-commands)
[2][Count items in a folder with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714284/count-items-in-a-folder-with-powershell)
[3][Powershell - remote folder availability while counting files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19862605/powershell-remote-folder-availability-while-counting-files)

Comment: You can't enumerate files on a share without having access to the share. Map a drive using explicit credentials, or grant the user running the code (usually the webserver service account) access to the share. Either way this is off topic on SO.

Comment: Can you please explain why this is off topic for SO? I found very similar questions on SO.

Comment: It's a system management problem rather than a programming problem.

Comment: Fair enough. Which network would you have suggested I post it on?

Comment: I'd consider [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) the best place for this kind of question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
set-location \\\storage\folder\

dir -recurse |  where-object{ $_.PSIsContainer } | ForEach{ Write-Host $_.FullName (dir $_.FullName | Measure-Object).Count }
```

This will count the number of files in each sub-folder (recurse) and display the full path and count in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that I can think of,

One would be to add -path to your get-childitem call. I tested this on my Powershell and it works fine.

`$files = get-childitem -path C:\temp
$files.count`
This returns the number of files in that path.

However I am testing this on a local file. If you are sure it is the remote access part giving you trouble I would suggest trying to set credentials. Besides the `get-credentials` option, you could also try setting them yourself.

`$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("Username", "password")`

Then perhaps you can set the drive and still be able to access your files. Hope that helps.